# Sed Script to add "std::" before each ocurrence of exception ( in a catch )

Tags: regex, sed

I've got this mission to recompile a legacy C++ project here in the company and after creating a 32-bit chroot, doing all the boring stuff of compiling dependencies and so on I finally found out that most of the files are using standard's exception class without adding  a 'using namespace std' or prefixing it with 'std::'.

I created a simple sed script to make change all the files in batch. But sometimes the replacement is not as I would like. My script is like this:

`sed -r 's/(catch.*)[^std::](exception)/\1 std::\2/' File.cpp`

But when I run it I get something like this ( grepping just the replacements ) :

```
}catch std::exception& e){
}catch(const std::exception& e){
}catch(const std::exception& e){
```

The original lines were this:

```
}catch(exception& e){
}catch(const exception& e){
}catch(const exception& e){
```

So, I get the problem when the catch is followed by "(exception" and it works fine when it's followed by (const ...)

I've tried to change the regex a little by trying to match the ( in the first back-reference expression i.e by changing it to "(catch.*\()" but it still doesn't work.

Anybody can give me a hand on that?

Thanks

Comment: `using std::exception;`?

Comment: although the language of your project is `C++` and it is concerning `namespace`s, the question itself isn't related to these topics at all. it is about text replacement (more specific, insertion) only. I removed the tags accordingly.

Comment: Stefan, you're right about the tags - thank you.

Comment: zch, I didn't want to use using std::exception because some files of the project are using boost::exception ( it's a legacy project ). Because of that I thought it was better to add std:: to each ocurrence. Still, because there was too many files with this problem it wouldn't help much to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^std::]` doesn't do what you think it does, it matches a single character which is not one of `'s'`, `'t'`, `'d'`, or `':'`, and whatever character it matches doesn't get put back in your substitution, which is why you lose the `(` character.  Also I bet if you look more carefully you've changed `catch(const exception` to `catch(const  std::exception` with an extra space.

You probably want:

```
sed -r 's/(catch.*[^:])(exception)/\1std::\2/' File.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[^std::]` part is bogus, as it matches a *single* character that is *not* `s`, `t`, `d` or `:`, which is not what you want. Instead, you want to skip all instances that contain the `std::exception` part. This works for me:

```
sed -r '/catch.*std::exception/!s/(catch.*)(exception)/\1 std::\2/' File.cpp
```